# Sanitize input in richtextbox to remove blank lines

Tags: powershell, sanitization

I am trying to sanitize input in a richtextbox to remove blank lines.

When I run the program it will sanitize the input and run the command.

Here is the code I am using to sanitize the input before commands are run:

```
$richtextbox1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt"
$richtextbox1.Text = $richtextbox1.Text -replace ";", "`n" -replace ",", "`n" -replace " ", ""
```

If it is a comma or semi-colon separated list it will separate each item into a new line so each line can later be entered into an array.

What I am looking to do is to find when a line is blank in the richtextbox and remove that line. Blank lines can happen when copying cells in from excel.

Any help would be appreciated. If you have any questions I will try my best to explain more.

Example Input in richtextbox:

```
Computer1, Computer2, Computer3, Computer4, Computer5
Computer6
(Blank space in input)
Computer7
```

Desired Sanitized Input:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
Computer4
Computer5
Computer6
Computer7
```

**EDIT:**I found a sloppy solution to this that will work for my application but maybe not for someone who needs to do this for a large amount of data. (I am not a huge programmer and only use it to make tools, so I am sure there is a way to do this more efficiently.)

```
$richtextbox1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt"
$richtextbox1.Text = $richtextbox1.Text -replace ";", "`n" -replace ",", "`n" -replace " ", ""

$computers = $richtextbox1.Text.Split("`n") | % { $_.trim() }
$richtextbox1.Text = ""
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    if ($computer -ne "")
    {
        $richtextbox1.AppendText("$computer`r")
    }
}
```

Comment: Could pipe those replaces into a `Where-Object{ $_ -match "\S"}` which would match non white space characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this line:

```
$richtextbox1.Text = $richtextbox1.Text -replace ";", "`n" -replace ",", "`n" -replace " ", ""
```

to

```
$richtextbox1.Text = $richtextbox1.Text -replace ";", "`n" -replace ",", "`n" -replace " ", "" -replace '(?s)(\n){2,}', "`n" -replace '\n$',''
```

The second to last replace will replace two or consecutive \n chars with a single \n to eliminate interior blank lines. The last replace is to eliminate the last \n.

Comment: I have used this in multiple programs at this point and now I have a situation where the first line is blank and this doesn't remove that line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a sloppy solution to this that will work for my application but maybe not for someone who needs to do this for a large amount of data. (I am not a huge programmer and only use it to make tools, so I am sure there is a way to do this more efficiently.)

```
$richtextbox1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt"
$richtextbox1.Text = $richtextbox1.Text -replace ";", "`n" -replace ",", "`n" -replace " ", ""

$computers = $richtextbox1.Text.Split("`n") | % { $_.trim() }
$richtextbox1.Text = ""
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    if ($computer -ne "")
    {
    $richtextbox1.AppendText("$computer`r")
    }
}
```